# Polygons can't be clicked after updating leaflet js to 1.x.x

Tags: leaflet, maps, ui-leaflet

I am using leaflet js + ui-leaflet for an application.

I updated my leaflet js version from `0.7.7` to `1.0.0`.

Now my Polygon paths have become unclickable. I have tried providing the `interactive`, `clickable` and `bubblingMouseEvents` flags when providing path options but to no avail.

Is there anything extra that i need to do to make sure click events are triggered? I am noticing specifically "leafletDirectivePath" events are not being triggered.

The only change is changing of leaflet js library version from 0.7.7 to 1.0.0.

I have also tried using other versions of ui-leaflet, including 3.0.0 and 2.0.0 as well.
Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: If you change your leaflet version, change it directly to 1.7.1

Comment: I did. I have tried other versions as well. I am unable to pinpoint as to what i need to change.